# Deserialize JSON Object C# with Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to deserialize the following:

```
{"result":{"success":true,"value":"8cb2237d0679ca88db6464eac60da96345513964"}}
```

to a C# object using Newtonsoft.Json

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
var json = wc.DownloadString(url);
Worker w = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Worker>(json);
```

Here is the class code:

```
public class Worker
{

    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public string success { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

The code does not error out, but the *success* and *value* are null.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the outer object.

```
public class Worker
{
     [JsonProperty("result")]
     public Result Result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public string Success { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Figured "result" needed to be serialized.

Comment: Also you may want to consider capitalizing your property names, since that is the standard convention in C#. Since you're already controlling the JSON serialization with attributes, it won't affect that. I edited my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: @luksan +1 What if I want the C# class to contain three fields: Result, Success and Value? When I set the JsonProperty attribute to "result.success" or "result.value" it returns null. Is it possible?

Comment: @Anar I'm not sure I understand. Maybe try creating a new question on here with example code.

Comment: My fault, sorry. I wanted to ask whether you could specify JsonProperty value two levels deep, hence, "result.success". It does not work that way, maybe you know a way.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you can do that. You would need to use two separate classes like in this example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that library, but success and result look to be both properties of the object "result"

Have you tried `[JsonProperty("result.success")]`?

Edit: Well, regardless it looks like a scoping issue. After viewing the documentation, this is my new suggestion:

```
public class Result{
 [JsonProperty("result")]
 public Worker result { get; set; }
}
```

then `Json.Convert.Deserialize<Result>(json)` instead.

Comment: Good thought... still Null.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any class and can make use of `dynamic` keyword

```
string json = @"{""result"":{""success"":true,""value"":""8cb2237d0679ca88db6464eac60da96345513964""}}";

dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", dynObj.result.success, dynObj.result.value);
```